# rdsadmin user logs in CloudWatch from Aurora Server Less DB Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I created Aurora Server Less DB Cluster (mysql5.10) on AWS.

then I enabled only slow query logs by setting keys in parameter cluster groups as -

```
slow_query_log : 1
long_query_time: 0.5
log_output: file
```

but In cluodWatch when I was looking for logs, I found logs-

- *My mysql user logs (which was expected)*
- *But there are so many **rdsadmin** logs. Even these logs do not match the criteria (long_query_time: 0.5).*

**Please help me to find out, is there a way to disable logs of rdsadmin from cloudwatch??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a clear answer on AWS site explaining which parameters are supported for RDS Serverless v1. After some quick test, I cant make the `long_query_time` parameter work with Serverless. Maybe the cluster need to be restarted, or we need to recreate a parameter group ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.parameter-groups

My solution is to **enable slow_query log** (it works), and **stream the log to CloudWatch Logs**.

Then I **query the log with CloudWatch Logs Insights** with the following query (assuming you have selected the slow_query log stream) :

```
parse @message "Query_time: *  Lock_time: * Rows_sent: * Rows_examined: *\n*" as Query_time,Lock_time,Rows_sent,Rows_examined,q
| filter Query_time > 0.250
```

It will display all query slower than 250ms.